# Find out what javascript function is resizing element on load with Firebug

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

Hi,

I have an element like this:

```
<div id="userlist-block-container" style="bottom: 100px; height: 282px;"></div>
```

the style is not really present in the original html but its being added by a javascript function. I need to find out which one and where is it so I can deactivate it and the element wont get resized. I would like to know if there is a way to do it with Firebug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome can help you identify all the functions that are executed on load:

1. Open Chrome Developer Tools.
2. Go to the *Elements* tab and click on *Event Listeners* tab in the side panel.
3. Expand *DOMContentLoaded* to view all functions.
4. You can click on the name of the function to view its source code and identify the one which is resizing the element you are concerned about.

[image: Screenotshot of the Developer Tool]

Comment: That looks more like chrome. Also, Im trying to find the javascript, not the CSS.

Comment: It is a Firefox developer tool. Element's style is mostly there on the CSS page unless there is an event handler attached to the element.

Comment: Okay, but again, I am not looking for the CSS, but the javascript which is modifying the element style.

Comment: Do you see any event handler like "onclick= "function name" or "onchange= function name" attached with your element? If yes then you can modify the javascript function else you will have to modify the CSS.

Comment: No, its not there. Its a function that runs on page load. I need to know which one is it.

Comment: Okay but please look at my question. I use Firefox so I would like to know how to do it on Firebug.